# Suggestion In Improving the code of webcam

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

I have written a basic code which captures an image from webcam using OpenCV & Python 2.7.

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow('image',frame)
cap.release()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code gives the correct output but my camera takes a few seconds to focus so I get a black or dim image as output instead of a bright proper focused image..

How can I solve this problem in a more mature way?

Comment: It is not clear what you need. "an alternate suggestion to do the same"? what? take a photo every 1.5 seconds? What's the actual problem?

Comment: @Akhorus updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You need an "auto capture" algorithm. Auto capturing algorithms are various depending on what your case is. For example if you need take a shoot for a document that you want to OCR it later, you have to  check how much this text is OCRable in order to take the image. However, in the general case there is something called **Reference-less Image Quality Assurance** that will help you to rate how much this image is good. Then, if it is good enough, take a shoot. However, implementing it is not an easy task.

If you need something fast and easy, just compute the sharpness of the image and depend on it to take the photo or not. See this :http://answers.opencv.org/question/5395/how-to-calculate-blurriness-and-sharpness-of-a-given-image/

Another option could be using a face detector if you are taking photos for humans. OpenCV has a cascade classifier with pre-trained model for human face. Just try to detect it and when it is detected, take the shoot.

You may also combine the last two types together in a hybrid mode. In other words, Detect the face then make sure it is sharp enough then take the photo

Answer (score 1):

You could wait till the video capturing has been initialized by modifying the code as:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("output")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if cap.isOpened():              # Getting the first frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
else:
    ret = False

while ret:
    cv2.imshow("output", frame)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27:                    # exit on Escape key
        break
cv2.destroyWindow("output")
```